# ManyToOne with FOSUSerBundle ignoring exclusion policy

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm

Building a JSON response for an API type thing, to retrieve a specific set of data that includes a ManyToOne relationship in the entity for my entity that extends FOSUSerBundle's User entity (called Account in my case).

The problem is, the Account entity thats included as a field in the response, is wanted, but I dont want to include all of the password and role type stuff.

I've been browing the internet for a couple hours now, and I've followed many guides on this, and I've cleared my cache every single time, and to no avail; So here's where I ended up:

```
// app/config/config.yml
jms_serializer:
  metadata:
    auto_detection: true
    directories:
      FOSUserBundle:
        namespace_prefix: "FOS\\UserBundle"
        path: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/serializer/FOS"
```

I've for below I've tried `User.Model.yml` and `Model.User.yml` and `User.Entity.yml` as well in a vain thought that the file name actually matters

```
// app/Resources/serializer/FOS/Entity.User.yml
FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:
  exclusion_policy: ALL
  properties:
    id:
      expose: true
```

and what I get still looks like this:

```
{
   "status":"ok",
   "api_version":"1.0",
   "code":200,
   "data":{
      "video":{
         "id":1,
         "published":true,
         "visibility":true,
         "title":"Megaman 2",
         "slug":"megaman-2",
         "summary":"A rap song about Megaman",
         "description":"A rap song\r\nAbout megaman",
         "youtube_id":"R6L9bUouDr8",
         "date_published":"2014-07-02T14:09:26-0700",
         "date_created":"2014-07-02T14:09:26-0700",
         "date_updated":"2014-07-02T14:09:26-0700",
         "author_id":3,
         "author":{
            "id":3,
            "username":"kharrison",
            "username_canonical":"kharrison",
            "email":"(sorry private)",
            "email_canonical":"(sorry, private)",
            "enabled":true,
            "salt":"(sorry, private)",
            "password":"(sorry, private)",
            "last_login":"2014-07-04T15:17:34-0700",
            "locked":false,
            "expired":false,
            "roles":[
               "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"
            ],
            "credentials_expired":false,
            "display_name":"Kyle Harrison",
            "slug":"kyle-harrison",
            "bio":"Test"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The "author" field, is my Account entity thats being run through the JMSSerializer

I want to exclude ALL of that, except the user ID, Display name, and slug.

And finally this is how the API works:

```
// My/Bundle/Controller/BaseAPIController.php
    //......... other code

    /**
     * @param string $status
     * @param integer $code
     * @return Response
     */
    public function render_api($status, $code)
    {
        $this->apiResponse->setStatus($status);
        $this->apiResponse->setCode($code);

        return new Response($this->apiResponse->serialize($this->get('jms_serializer')), $this->apiResponse->getCode(), ["Content-type"=>"application/json"]);
    }

    //............. other code
```

and finally, that calls this:

```
// My/Bundle/Models
class APIResponse {

    protected $status;
    protected $apiVersion;
    protected $code;
    protected $data;

    public function __construct($apiVersion, $status = "OK", $code = 500)
    {
        $this->status = $status;
        $this->code = $code;
        $this->apiVersion = $apiVersion;
        $this->data = [];
    }

    // ... getters and setters

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function serialize($serializer) {
        return $serializer->serialize($this, "json");
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you by any chance re-define the properties in your `Account` entity (that extends FOSUserBundle's `User` model)?

Comment: I beleive that was one of the first things I tried. But you know it's been so long now, it's worth another shot

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not what I meant. You shouldn't re-define them in your `Account` entity. But if you did, that could've been the reason why your serializer config doesn't work. (you should always create the configuration for the class that defines the properties, in order for it to work)

Comment: Ah yeah, explicitly what I was getting at (early morning grogginess) was the original thing I tried to do, was use JMSSerializerBundle's Annotation system, which the documentations informed me to overload each property I wanted exposed while blanketing the Account entity with an Exclusion policy of `ALL`. This didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok So, the actual answer, couldn't have been arrived to via the information I provided.  But Nic's Answer did lead me towards the solution.  The description of how the the serializer looks at and deciphers the config file lead me to the real problem at hand.

This is what I failed to show:

```
<?php

namespace [PRIVATE]\[PRIVATE]Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\VirtualProperty;

/**
 * Account
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="[PRIVATE]\[PRIVATE]Bundle\Entity\AccountRepository")
 */
class Account extends BaseUser
{
```

The problem lays with the Alias I provided the `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` namespace. I no longer remember why I wrote that that way.  However, the moment I remove the Alias and rewrote the extends to resemble this instead:

```
<?php

namespace [PRIVATE]\[PRIVATE]Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\VirtualProperty;

/**
 * Account
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="[PRIVATE]\[PRIVATE]Bundle\Entity\AccountRepository")
 */
class Account extends User
{
```

combined with the new correct filename from Nic's answer, the config based Exclusion policy for JMSSerializerBundle totally kicks in, and every instance of FOSUserBundle's items are now completely hidden, except for the fields I've now explicitly told it to expose.

This is exactly what I wanted :)

Thanks everyone for your help! Cheers

~k

Answer (score 2):

> I've for below I've tried `User.Model.yml` and `Model.User.yml` and
>   `User.Entity.yml` as well in a vain thought that the file name actually
>   matters.

It does matter, actually. It's a concatenation of the namespace and class name. In this case, you're trying to configure the `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` class, so the file name should be `Model.User.yml`. (`FOS\UserBundle\` should be excluded from the file name, since you configured it as `namespace_prefix` in your `config.yml`)

Also make sure that your `Account` class doesn't re-declare (overwrite) the properties, as the serializer config only works if you configure it for the class that actually declares the properties.

Comment: I'm.. uhh.. really embarrassed actually.  Your explanation of the filename was definitely useful as one half of the problem I was having, thats for sure (as the filename I was using, reverts the change back). But the other problem comes from something I failed to display.  The `Account` entity I setup, gave an alias to the `use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` with an `as BaseUser` (for some reason, I no longer remember why I did that). Removing the alias, and subsequently updating my `extends` to `User` instead of `BaseUser` TOTALLY worked!!   **does a happy dance**

Comment: Good to hear you solved it! But I'm still curious as to what caused the problem. Are you certain that it was caused by the alias?

Comment: Well it's the only thing that I changed that caused the issue to be fixed. My direct thought as to what happened, is that the Alias was  allowing the Account Entity to inherit the User class, but wasn't being caught by JMSSerializerBundle as it's explicitly looking for instances of the User class.  As far as I understand,  it *shouldn't* matter if an alias is used or not, but the SerializerBundle is probably intercepting at a moment where the alias is applied and thus being missed by the filter.  I haven't tested but I suspect if I specified `FOS\UserBundle\Model\BaseUser` it'd have worked :\

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the exact way you want it, more a way around:

way around 1: Select only the properties you want (via the entity manager) and then serialize the array obtained.

It's what I do with what I call my API (which is not a class as you but controllers)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response! May I request a bit more elaboration on what you mean by `Select only the properties you want (via the entity manager)`? As in the YML I'm specifying the exclusion policy as `ALL` and determining that `id` is the only exposed property to the `JMSSerializerBundle` configuration, yet I'm getting all of my properties back :(

Comment: I meant that you can do otherwise, not by serializing your entity. But rather make a request for just a few fields and then serialize this result. Another way I did in one of my entity:you write a method that is a get of only a few properties and then serialize this method only.

Comment: The only problem with this approach, is that the only problem is the Account entity which exposes some sensitive data. The Account entity is never called explicitly by code, it's acquired by Doctrine's automatic hydration system with Foreign Key associations, and the architecture of the entities gets pretty deep (it could be anywhere). I don't have a DQL Query, nor do I find it explicitly entertaining to have to write one to undermine the entire point of the `*To*` associations by having to craft a specific DQL with Joins for a single cause that doesnt benefit the whole site with the change

Comment: I do understand what you mean though, I've done that before, just acquire the data in controllers and feed specific data to the serialized output.  And that's a totally legit approach.  In the API I'm writing however, for example, that Account entity can (and does) exist in multiple nested Entities and can (and does) exist multiple times in the same entity.  Writing some way to acquire that data and then parse it out manually for only a single reason and space, seems to go against the entire point of using Doctrine's ORM to me..  Though if it gets to that point, It's not out of the question

Comment: I understand. Actually I'm going to have the same problem anytime soon and will use this threa. so thank you as well :)

Comment: Make sure to upvote and favorite it then ;) I could use the reputation points back from the bounty haha